# Elasticsearch post aggregation string filter

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I have a system with devices that communicate through some gateways, and then in backend metrics are saved in elasticsearch.

I want to know the sensors that are now communicating through a specific gateway_id.

I have a mapping like this one:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "context": {
        "properties": {
          "gateway": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
}},
      "timeserver": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the gateway field is saved, as a string, the id of the gateway used for each metric.

I am able to get the last communication for each device, with this query:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "context.id.keyword"
        , "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": "measurements.group.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I filter this aggregation result, to get only the sensors that are currently using a specific gateway? Adding something like: `"filter": {"term":{"context.gateway": {"value": "request_gateway_serial" }} },`

I have searched for bucket_selector aggregation, and pipeline aggregations, but didn't find a way, and looks to me that they only work with numeric values, no strings, like my gateway field.

Query example returns:(A list of the most recent communication for each device)

```
"aggregations" : {
          {
            "key" : "1234",

                "context" : {
                  "gateway" : "123456",
                  "id" : "1234", 
          },{
            "key" : "12345",
                      "context" : {
                        "gateway" : "1234567",
                        "id" : "12345",
          }, {
             "key" : "12345678",
                     "context" : {
                        "gateway" : "1234567",
                        "id" : "12345678",
}}
```

My expected result is then filter for "gateway" : "1234567", and get only "key" : "12345"and "key" : "12345678"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

```
GET sensors/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter_gateway": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "context.gateway.keyword": "request_gateway_serial"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "context.id.keyword",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "timestamp": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": "measurements.group.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on you requirement you can also  filter documents in query part and then perform aggregation on it.

EDIT 1:

In below query I am getting maximum timestamp under a device id
and maximum timestamp filtered on given gateway. If both the dates are same it will give the device id which communicated last with the gateway.

ex.

Query:

```
GET sensors/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "context.id.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxDate": {
          "max": {
            "field": "context.timestamp"
          }
        },
        "Filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "context.gateway": "1234568"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_maxdate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "context.timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "last_geteway_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "filtereddate": "Filter>filtered_maxdate",
              "maxDate": "maxDate"
            },
            "script": "params.filtereddate==params.maxDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "sensors",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "eiZ1pW0BcOVYVz455V6s",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "context.gateway" : "1234567",
          "context.id" : 1234,
          "context.timestamp" : "2019-10-02"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sensors",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "eyZ2pW0BcOVYVz45B14T",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "context.gateway" : "1234568",
          "context.id" : 1234,
          "context.timestamp" : "2019-10-03"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sensors",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fCZ2pW0BcOVYVz45Jl6m",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "context.gateway" : "1234569",
          "context.id" : 1234,
          "context.timestamp" : "2019-10-04"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sensors",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fSZ2pW0BcOVYVz45dV48",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "context.gateway" : "1234567",
          "context.id" : 1235,
          "context.timestamp" : "2019-10-02"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sensors",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fiZ2pW0BcOVYVz45l17A",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "context.gateway" : "1234568",
          "context.id" : 1235,
          "context.timestamp" : "2019-10-03"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Result:

```
Device 12345 had last document under gateway 1234568

"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1235",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "Filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filtered_maxdate" : {
              "value" : 1.5700608E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          "maxDate" : {
            "value" : 1.5700608E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think it is not a solution.

I want to filter "after" the aggregation results and, I think that, Filter Aggregation filters during the aggregation. So I will get the list os all the devices that have communicated through the specific gateway, and not the list of all devices that are now communicating through that specific gateway.
"Filter Aggregation- Defines a single bucket of all the documents in the current document set context that match a specified filter. Often this will be used to narrow down the current aggregation context to a specific set of documents."

Comment: what will be the criteria for that , how to know which devices are communicating? . can you add sample data and elaborate the question

Comment: I my query example I get,  in the aggregation, the last communication for each device, then my expectation is to filter these results to get only that ones on that the gateway field match the requested_gateway.

Comment: Can you add a sample data and expected result based on that, will help to better visualize it.

Comment: Above query should achieve the same. Filter for all gateway: 1234567 and get id under it . I don't see the need for bucket selector which will be used if we want to select parent bucket based on data in child bucket

Comment: No, your query gives me " The last communication of each sensor through the request_gateway_serial" and not the " devices that are now communicating through the request_gateway_serial". Your firlter is done during the aggregation, and I need after the aggregation, on their results. Thanks

Comment: So do you indent to place a range check on some time stamp field ?. The confusion I have is how to detect which device is communicating now- on basis of which field and criteria

Comment: The criteria that I need is the gateway, {"term":{"context.gateway": {"value": "request_gateway_serial" }}.
Process: query on specific group of devices, aggregate on their last communication, and filter for request_gateway_serial, getting only devices that on their last communication have the field gateway equals to request_gateway_serial

Comment: Ok I get it now, will check and get back

Comment: Thanks for the effort, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I have updated the query under EDIT1, check if it serves your purpose

Comment: Thanks, for the help

Comment: Glad could be of help

Comment: Hi @jaspreet On this same query example, how can I get the bucket count number